# Building pjsip for x86

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

I want to build pjsip for x86 architecture. I am following this [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android). In the instructions,

Building PJSIP

Just run:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir 
$ ./configure-android
$ make dep && make clean && make
```

Notes:

It will build armeabi target, to build for other targets such as arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, instead of just './configure-android', specify the target arch in TARGET_ABI and run it with --use-ndk-cflags, for example:

TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags

**Also you should adjust ​Application.mk and ​library packaging path (see also #1803).**

Are they referring Application.mk in pjsua application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is link in ticket #1803 on changeset 5056:

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/5056

`Android.mk` and `Application.mk` you can find here: `your-pjsip-root-dir/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/android/jni/Application.mk`